# How to find a key that corresponds to a value in a hashmap without iterating the table (Java)

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I'm trying to create an extension to HashMap that modifies the put function.  The goal is to have the put function not allow duplicate values.  So, if someone tried to insert the key/value (B,a) when the key/value (A,a) was already in the map, then it would replace the key /value (A,a) with (B,a) rather than create a new key/value pair.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to find a key that corresponds with a value without iterating the table (which I can't do since table is a private variable and I can't access it from within my function extension).

I have also tried to retrieve the set of keys with keySet() with the intention of running get() operations on every single key, but the set variable is really confusing me and I'm not sure how to correctly iterate and run get() operations on the individual elements.

EDIT:
Here is what I have so far:
import java.util.*;

public class UniqueHashMap extends HashMap {

```
public V put(K key, V value) {

    boolean contains = containsValue(value);
    if (contains == true)
        // INSERT CODE HERE
    else
        return super.put(key, value);

}
```

}

In the if statement, what I want to do is be able to:
1) Locate the key corresponding to "value".
2) Delete the key.
3) Insert the new key/value pair.

The part I'm having trouble with is 1) because most of the solutions I've seen need access to the map (which I don't know how to get since it's a private variable in HashMap).  I can get access to the keys using keySet(), but I don't know how to iteratively run get() operations on the individual keys because I am confused about the set variable.

Comment: Why don't you simply swap key and value? Seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It seems that you're using HashMap incorrectly. The key should be a unique qualifier to represent the value. I agree with @Smutje - it sounds like your VALUE is actually your KEY.

Comment: I don't want to swap the key and value though.  I want both the keys and values to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) method of `Map`. This allows you to iterate over the pairs of key and corresponding value together:

```
public void put(K key, V val) {
  Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = entrySet().iterator();
  while (entries.hasNext()) {
    if (entries.next().getValue().equals(val)) {
      entries.remove();
      break;
    }
  }
  super.put(key, val);
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! Finally got this working now! Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class MyHashMap<K, V> {
    private HashMap<K, V> map;

    void put(K key, V value) {
        if (map.containsValue(value)) {
            K keyToRemove = findKeyByValue(value);
            map.remove(keyToRemove);
            map.put(key, value);
        } else {
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    private K findKeyByValue(V val) {
        for (Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (val == e.getValue())
                return e.getKey();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But note that this way you will lose HashMap's constant complexity of `put` method.

EDIT: Included a compilable class

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this out, but the problem is that I don't have access to Entry since it's not a public variable in HashMap.  I can get the list of keys using keySet(), but then I don't know how to do individual get() operations on the keys since there seems to be some problem with the variable type.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't access the entry? EntrySet is a public method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29). By iterating it you can get every entry.

Comment: When I try to run it, I get the error:
Entry is not public in HashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package.

Apologies - I haven't done much programming in years and am new to Java.

Comment: I pasted a compilable class; see my edited post. That works for me. Which java version do you have?

Comment: Running the latest version of Java.  Still getting the same error though.  I edited my original post to show my code.  I tried inserting your findKeyByValue function below my own code and I get that error about Entry not being accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend HashMap (might be better to implement the Map yourself and use a HashMap to implement it incase they add more add methods), and override the add methods and on each one:

```
If HashMap contains the key already
    grab the instance that the key refers to and remove it from the map, and re-put that instance into the map with the supplied key instead of the old key
Else
    Just put with the supplied key and value.
```

Keep track of what value was last associated with the key with an internal HashSet, this is so you can do an O(1) remove for that If portion above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). It was designed to handle this case as it is a bi-directional map.

You would call `Object key = myBiMap.inverse().get( myValue );`.